# when i edit the linux kernel code, what is the process of building and running the modified kernel?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux

I am learning how to write some code in the Linux kernel, and i would like to start practicing writing code in the kernel, but my question is what is the process of building and running the modified kernel?
should I just each time, when I modify the kernel code, to recompile the kernel, reinstall it on my machine and then reboot my machine, or is there another way of doing this process in the real life, in the industry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, easiest is if you can have the code you're modifying in a *module*, then you can remove the old version and load in the new version.

Alternatively, you could run the kernel in a virtual machine inside your host computer! That way you need to only reboot the virtual machine, not the entire physical computer.

Comment: And if you do need to do a reboot (whether physical or virtual machine) it would be a good idea to create some sort of secondary boot configuration that you can trigger in your boot manager, keep the primary a known good kernel (that is without your modifications) so that you don't accidentally make the machine unbootable.